# Make compiling target multiple times

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile setup which generates two elf files. The elf files have two inputs, one common and one unique. I'm trying have the common input (main.c) only get compiled once.

I have the following example which mimics my setup:

```
Makefile
proj
  - main.c
  - print.c
  - Makefile
```

The root Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all
all: proj/build/0/0.elf proj/build/1/1.elf

proj/build/0/0.elf:
    $(MAKE) -C proj VARIANT=0 all
proj/build/1/1.elf:
    $(MAKE) -C proj VARIANT=1 all
```

proj/Makefile:

```
COMMON_SRCS = main.c
VARIANT_SRCS = print.c

BUILD_DIR_COMMON = build/common
BUILD_DIR_VARIANT= build/$(VARIANT)

OBJECTS += $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR_COMMON)/,$(COMMON_SRCS:.c=.o))
OBJECTS += $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR_VARIANT)/,$(VARIANT_SRCS:.c=.o))

.PHONY: all
all: $(BUILD_DIR_VARIANT)/$(VARIANT).elf

$(BUILD_DIR_COMMON)/%.o: %.c
    @mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR_COMMON)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR_VARIANT)/%.o: %.c
    @mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR_VARIANT)
    $(CC) -DVARIANT=$(VARIANT) -c $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR_VARIANT)/$(VARIANT).elf: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $@
```

The .c files don't really matter, just know that print.c uses the VARIANT define.

When I run `make` in the root directory, I get the following output:

```
make -C proj VARIANT=0 all
make -C proj VARIANT=1 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/phil/dev/make_test/proj'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/phil/dev/make_test/proj'
cc -c main.c -o build/common/main.o
cc -c main.c -o build/common/main.o
cc -DVARIANT=0 -c print.c -o build/0/print.o
cc build/common/main.o build/0/print.o -o build/0/0.elf
cc -DVARIANT=1 -c print.c -o build/1/print.o
cc build/common/main.o build/1/print.o -o build/1/1.elf
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/phil/dev/make_test/proj'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/phil/dev/make_test/proj'
```

As you can see from the output, main.c gets compiled twice. I'm looking for some options which makes it only compile once without completly changing my project structure

Comment: Interesting, I can reproduce this behavior only if I run `make -j2`. In this case, it's a simple race condition, which can be avoided by eliminating `make` recursion (which is considered evil by many).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delegate your build to two different make invocations and expect them to cooperate. If something is common to your two builds, the best is to put it in your top-level Makefile:

```
# Makefile
.PHONY: all
all: proj/build/0/0.elf proj/build/1/1.elf

COMMON_SRCS = main.c

BUILD_DIR_COMMON = build/common

OBJECTS += $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR_COMMON)/,$(COMMON_SRCS:.c=.o))

$(BUILD_DIR_COMMON)/%.o: %.c
    @mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR_COMMON)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

proj/build/0/0.elf: $(OBJECTS)
    $(MAKE) -C proj VARIANT=0 all

proj/build/1/1.elf: $(OBJECTS)
    $(MAKE) -C proj VARIANT=1 all
```

And:

```
# proj/Makefile
COMMON_SRCS = main.c
VARIANT_SRCS = print.c

BUILD_DIR_COMMON = build/common
BUILD_DIR_VARIANT= build/$(VARIANT)

OBJECTS += $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR_COMMON)/,$(COMMON_SRCS:.c=.o))
OBJECTS += $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR_VARIANT)/,$(VARIANT_SRCS:.c=.o))

.PHONY: all
all: $(BUILD_DIR_VARIANT)/$(VARIANT).elf

$(BUILD_DIR_VARIANT)/%.o: %.c
    @mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR_VARIANT)
    $(CC) -DVARIANT=$(VARIANT) -c $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR_VARIANT)/$(VARIANT).elf: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $@
```

One drawback of this reorganization is that you cannot build a single variant from scratch any more. As they depend on external components you must build these external components first. Recursive make is fine when the sub-parts are really independent, self-contained, projects. A non-recursive make approach would maybe be better. Example:

```
# Makefile
VARIANTS         := 0 1 2 3
COMMON_SRCS      := main.c
VARIANT_SRCS     := print.c
BUILD_DIR_COMMON := proj/build/common

.PHONY: all

$(BUILD_DIR_COMMON)/%.o: proj/%.c | $(BUILD_DIR_COMMON)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR_COMMON):
    @mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR_COMMON)

define VARIANT_rule
.PHONY: V$(1)

BUILD_DIR_VARIANT_$(1) := proj/build/$(1)
OBJECTS_$(1) := $$(patsubst %.c,$$(BUILD_DIR_COMMON)/%.o,$$(COMMON_SRCS))
OBJECTS_$(1) += $$(patsubst %.c,$$(BUILD_DIR_VARIANT_$(1))/%.o,$$(VARIANT_SRCS))

all V$(1): $$(BUILD_DIR_VARIANT_$(1))/$(1).elf

$$(BUILD_DIR_VARIANT_$(1))/%.o: proj/%.c | $$(BUILD_DIR_VARIANT_$(1))
    $$(CC) -DVARIANT=$(1) -c $$< -o $$@

$$(BUILD_DIR_VARIANT_$(1)):
    @mkdir -p $$@

$$(BUILD_DIR_VARIANT_$(1))/$(1).elf: $$(OBJECTS_$(1))
    $$(CC) $$^ -o $$@
endef
$(foreach v,$(VARIANTS),$(eval $(call VARIANT_rule,$(v))))
```

And then, to build all variants:

```
$ make all
```

While to build only variants 1 and 3:

```
$ make V1 V3
```

Comment: You explination makes sense and this does work, however now there isn't a good split between makefiles. I can no longer run `VARIANT=3 make` from proj. Maybe it would be best for my project to try and combine these Makefiles

Comment: Yes, recursive make is fine when the sub-parts are really independent self-contained projects. In your case they depend on external components. A non-recursive make approach would probably be better. I updated my answer to show an (untested) example of non-recursive Makefile. Note: tanks to inclusions, you can still split your Makefile in smaller parts, if you wish.